# MySQL UPDATE Not Updating any row

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with the following syntax:

```
    if( isset($_POST['save_changes']) ) {
    // Get current id of customer
    $currentID = $_GET['id'];
    // Get Input Values
    $newfirstName        = validateInputData($_POST['first_name']);
    $newlastName         = validateInputData($_POST['last_name']);
    $newemail            = validateInputData($_POST['email']);
    $newphone            = validateInputData($_POST['phone_number']);
    $newaddressOne       = validateInputData($_POST['address_one']);
    $newaddressTwo       = validateInputData($_POST['address_two']);
    $newcounty           = validateInputData($_POST['county']);
    $newcity             = validateInputData($_POST['city']);
    $newzipCode          = validateInputData($_POST['zip_code']);
    $newprovince         = validateInputData($_POST['province']);
    $newstate            = validateInputData($_POST['state']);

    // Queries
    $query = "UPDATE customers 
              SET 
              first_name='$newfirstName', 
              last_name='$newlastName', 
              email='$newemail', 
              phone='$newphone'
              WHERE id='$currentID'
              ";
    $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

    $query = "UPDATE addresses
              SET 
              address_one='$newaddressOne', 
              address_two='$newaddressTwo', 
              county='$newcounty', 
              city='$newcity', 
              province='$newprovince', 
              zip_code='$newzipCode', 
              state='$newstate'
              WHERE customer_id='$currentID'
              ";
    $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

    // Bring user back to index
    header("Location: index.php?alert=savechanges");

    // Close connection to database
    $conn->close();
  }
```

the above query runs fine, but the row is not updated. all the field names are appropriate. When the query is tried in phpMyAdmin, row updated.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: No error appearing?

Comment: Inside the if statement `echo "save_changes was set";exit;` and see if it outputs.

Comment: Nothing happen. All runs smoothly. When i'm using affected_rows funtions, the value is Null.

Comment: echo the query and share the output

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: I have a feeling `validateInputData` doen't properly escape things and this is full of holes. If your query isn't obviously safe, it's best to presume it isn't safe.

Comment: validateInputData function: function validateInputData( $inputData ) {
 $inputData = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($inputData)));
 return $inputData;
}

Comment: This is strange you are getting half of values through $_POST and id through $_GET,  `$currentID = $_GET['id'];` make sure this is valid otherwise it should be sth like ` $currentID = $_POST['id'];` and as @tadman suggested use PDO

Comment: That validation function is dangerously inadequate and does absolutely nothing but mangle your data while completely ignoring SQL injection concerns. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. Do not use `stripslashes`. Use `htmlspecialchars` *only* for displaying data *from* the database that has been entered by users. Sorry about being harsh here, but any muppet with a [testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) could can-opener your site in five seconds if they thought to try.

Comment: @sakhunzai the url is edit_customer.php?id=2, so i grab the id using $_GET. There is other method should i use?

Comment: add a hidden input and put id there and collect it through $_POST['id']. and on the top put var_dump($_POST) ; exit and verify you are getting all the values

Comment: After trying a variety of ways, and finally I use PDO as suggested by @tadman and create a variable that holds the id with a value taken from a hidden input as suggested by sakhunzai. Basically, what happens is a bug caused by the $ _GET method used to retrieve the id value that comes from the URL. Thank you for your suggestion, tadman and sakhunzai.

Answer (score -1):

Your validateInputData() function is not doing any validation. Hopefully it's doing some escaping, implying that you are assuming global scope for your database connection object. You didn't tell us what type of database object this is. Your error checking is poor. You don't do an explicit exit after the redirect.

Apart from that the sql looks ok.